# Нужны ли отдельные пользователи MySQL для каждого потока при использовании Python QThreads?

Tags: python, mysql, многопоточность

Хочу добавить в свой проект один-два `QThreads` для того чтобы разгрузить основной поток с интерфейсом.
Каждый поток будет работать с бд `MySQL` через `MySQL.Connector`.

Возник такой тупенький вопрос: Нужно ли каждому потоку задавать не только свое подключение, но и своего пользователя? Или `MySQL` будет Ок, если в него одновременно прилетит 2-3 `Connect` от одного пользователя, и он корректно обработает, даже если запросы будут +- одновременно?

PS Различий в правах доступа и.т.п. для потоков не планируется.

PPS Подключения будут примерно вот такие:

```
from mysql.connector import connect, Error

try:
    with connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="User", # Нужно ли для Thread1 создать User1, и.т.п.? 
        password="Password",
    ) as connection:
        print(connection)
except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Нет смысла создавать отдельных пользователей. Только если нужно разграничивать доступ разве - но, как я понимаю, оно не требуется.

Comment: @Akina Ага, спасибо. Чего то не нашел в интернете информации об этом. И да, разграничения доступа и.т.п. не требуется, просто возник вопрос и отказался уходить из головы =). Значит `MySQL`у все ок с тем что в него от одного пользователя несколько коннектов стучатся. =)

Comment: Для одного аккаунта есть ограничения - количество параллельных подключений, количество подключений в час и пр. - см. RM. Но это всё настраивается.